# PHP function for changing values in array from database

Tags: php, arrays, fetchall

I have array with values from database

```
$values = $sql->fetchAll();
```

Which looks like this:

```
var_dump($values);

array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'level' => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'level' => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      'level' => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
```

What I am trying to do is to change level to for example 5, where player id = 3. I need to change both level related values. Number or array keys and their position may vary depending on SQL query. I need function which would take following arguments: $playerID, $keyName, $value and then it would change appropriate values.

For example:

```
function($playerID, $keyName, $value);
function(3, "level", 5);
```

Array after changes would look like this:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'level' => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'level' => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      'level' => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
```

Comment: Can you rpivide us the `print_r($values)` or your array,`var_dump` is pretty confusing and clumsy here?

Comment: Sure Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [level] => 0 [1] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [0] => 2 [level] => 3 [1] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [0] => 3 [level] => 0 [1] => 0 ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    function changeVal($values, $playerID, $keyName, $value)
    {
        foreach($values as $key => $val)
       {
           if ($val['id'] == $playerID)
           {
             $values[$key][$keyName] = $value;
             $index = array_search($keyName, array_keys($values))+1;
             $values[$key][$index] = $value;
           }
        }
    }

 changeVal($values , 3, "level", 5);
```

Comment: this only changes values for "level" index but not for "1" index

Comment: Yes, but this will not work if the level value represented by number index will be on different position, for example if I use different SQL query. I need more universal function.

Comment: '**level value represented by number index will be on different position**' , can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: in this case index "level" and index "1" are both representing the same value so I need to change them both.

Comment: I think what would be better is to find what position $keyName index has ("level" is 3rd index in this example) and change value of n+1 index. Is something like this possible? PS: indexes are always in this order 1: string representation (eg. "level") 2: number representation (eg. "1")

Answer (score 0):

**PHP >= 5.5.0**

```
function changeRow(&$rows, $playerID, $keyName, $value) {
    $key = array_search($playerID, array_column($rows, 'id'));
    $rows[$key][$keyName] = $value;
}

changeRow($values, 3, 'level', 5);
```